# What would cause `whereis(user)` to return undefined?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

We're running RabbitMQ 3.6.5 on a production system, under

```
Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
```

`rabbitmqctl rotate_logs` fails with:

```
Erlang VM I/O system is damaged, restart needed
```

Looking at the code for that version, this error exists only in in `rabbit_log.erl`:

```
...

%% Execute Fun using the IO system of the local node (i.e. the node on
%% which the code is executing). Since this is invoked for every log
%% message, we try to avoid unnecessarily churning group_leader/1.
with_local_io(Fun) ->
    GL = group_leader(),
    Node = node(),
    case node(GL) of
        Node -> Fun();
        _    -> set_group_leader_to_user_safely(whereis(user)),
                try
                    Fun()
                after
                    group_leader(GL, self())
                end
    end.

set_group_leader_to_user_safely(undefined) ->
    handle_damaged_io_system();
set_group_leader_to_user_safely(User) when is_pid(User) ->
    group_leader(User, self()).

handle_damaged_io_system() ->
    Msg = "Erlang VM I/O system is damaged, restart needed~n",
    io:format(standard_error, Msg, []),
    exit(erlang_vm_restart_needed).
```

So, it appears that `whereis(user)` is returning `undefined`.

This error is not occurring in a test system running the same version, which means I've so far been unable to reproduce the error
in a non-production system where I can try corrective action. Since the failure is in a production system, a key goal is to
correct this in the least disruptive way possible.

I hope to understand the likelihood that this is something that would prevent rabbit from starting up again, and whether
a restart of RabbitMQ will correct this.

The log `startup_err` contains:

```
Erlang VM I/O system is damaged, restart needed
```

The log `rabbit@fdlquevm-sasl.log-20180710` contains:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 28-Nov-2018::18:45:04 ===
     Supervisor: {<0.26938.6080>,rabbit_channel_sup}
     Context:    shutdown_error
     Reason:     noproc
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.26217.6080>},
                  {name,channel},
                  {mfargs,
                      {rabbit_channel,start_link,
                          [1,<0.27525.6080>,<0.25586.6080>,<0.27525.6080>,
                           <<"40.113.233.192:3979 -> 10.0.0.4:5672">>,
                           rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
                           {user,<<"FDLMessaging">>,[],
                               [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
                           <<"/">>,
                           [{<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
                            {<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
                            {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
                            {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true},
                            {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
                            {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true}],
                           <0.26295.6080>,<0.22812.6080>]}},
                  {restart_type,intrinsic},
                  {shutdown,70000},
                  {child_type,worker}]
```

What would cause `whereis(user)` to return undefined?

Comment: What version of Erlang are you using? Is there anything interesting in the RabbitMQ logs? [This web page](https://ferd.ca/repl-a-bit-more-and-less-than-that.html) explains what the `user` process is and what it does. Note that RabbitMQ `3.7.X` versions do not have this code because logging switched to the `lager` library.

Comment: One more thing, asking these sorts of questions on [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) is preferred as the RabbitMQ core engineering team monitors it.

Comment: @LukeBakken - Added Erlang version to the question. Thanks for the link to rabbitmq-users, too.

Comment: @LukeBakken - Now the question includes the logging info, too.

Answer (score 1):

The `user` process is a central process that handles most of I/O related to standard output. By default, it will always exist, unless the `-nouser` argument is given to the underlying Erlang virtual machine.

The other way this process could fail is if it had been killed by another rogue process, or reaped by the VM doing something like killing a process using too much memory, or because it referenced code that has been hot-code loaded too many times and it needed to purge it.

It should essentially never happen unless someone or something is willingly poking at that code.